# How to change background color when selecting row of NSOutlineView?

Tags: view, colors, nsoutlineview

I am using `NSOutlineView` in view-based mode, but I do not know how to change the background color of selected row?

I found some cell-based model answers but they do not apply to me.

Comment: To steal a comment that is valid here: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new you may not be aware, but a good question should show some attempt at the problem and ask a focused question about a concept that is not clear. Open ended questions asking for general guidance, or for code, are not really well received.

Comment: - (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView didClickTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn